# Link does not parse correctly (dollar sign)

Tags: bug

Yesterday, I gave an answer to the question on SO ([Calling custom method before session auto destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044950/calling-custom-method-before-session-auto-destroy/34045215#34045215), already edited by community)

In this question I posted a link to YII docs -

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#$handler-detail

On preview, this link is parsed correctly, but when I post the answer, the link was not parsed correctly and looks bad - everything after dollar sign was not clickable (you can see it right now).

I've already wrote a letter to SO support and they say that I need to post this here.